# ReportAvOnComRelease was detected

Tags: c#, vb.net

Sorry for the inconvenience, I have a question again. 
I'm having a very not common error in VB.NET (see error below).
I think it is all about COM problems, but i'm not aware of it.
This is happened while i'm at the winsock_dataArrival function.
Please help and respect, i'm just a .NET beginner.
I also attached picture below.

> ReportAvOnComRelease was detected

```
Message: An exception was caught but handled while releasing a COM interface pointer through Marshal.Release or Marshal.ReleaseComObject or implicitly after the corresponding RuntimeCallableWrapper was garbage collected. This is the result of a user refcount error or other problem with a COM object's Release. Make sure refcounts are managed properly.  The COM interface pointer's original vtable pointer was 0x27582bb8. While these types of exceptions are caught by the CLR, they can still lead to corruption and data loss so if possible the issue causing the exception should be addressed
```

Code:

```
Private Sub Winsock1_DataArrival(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_DataArrivalEvent) Handles Winsock1.DataArrival

        Dim strData As String = ""
        Dim msg As String
        Dim i As Integer
        Static bmsg As Boolean

        On Error Resume Next
        peer.GetData(strData)
        peer.RemoteHost = HOST

        If checkMSG(i) Then
            If b_QALoad Then
                dlgQA.setMSG()
            Else
                If MsgBox("You have " & i & " unread message(s)." & vbCrLf & "Do you want to read it now?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.Information, MYPS_ABR) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                    dlgQA.ShowDialog()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

[ReportAvOnComRelease was detected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UakiW.png)

Comment: Using the olden VB6 Winsock control is a mistake.  Use the classes in the System.Net namespace instead.

Comment: UP! need help thanks admin. =))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the code triggered below, lets say it is in the module1..
"frmdlg.closeform()"

It calls this procedure..
Code:

```
Public Sub closeform()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

Then after, I exited in that module1 then i am now at the module2. I noticed some codes.
There is also "Me.Close", i'm wondering It is already closed but the program calls it again.
Then, I turned it into comment for the meantime..
Then, VIOLA! No more error occurred. ^^